# Dojo 1.9 JsonRest remote url on a different server

Tags: json, dojo

I'm trying to get dojo to show Json data that comes from a remote web service.  I need to be clear though - the web server hosting the html/dojo page I access isn't the same server as the one that's running the web service that returns the json data - the web service server just can't serve html pages reliably (don't ask!!).

As a test I move the page into the same web server as the web service and the below works.  As soon as I move it back so that the html/dojo is served from Apache (//myhost.nodomain:82 say) and the web service sending the json is "{target:http://myhost.nodomain:8181}", then it stops working.

I've used FFox to look at the network & I see the web service being called ok, the json data is returned too & looks correct (I know it is from the previous test), but the fields are no longer set.  I've tried this with DataGrid and the plain page below with the same effects.

Am I tripping up over something obvious???

Thanks

```
    require([
            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/query",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ],
        function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query) {

            var myStore, dataStore, grid;
            myStore = JsonRest(
                                    {
                                        target: "http://localhost:8181/ws/job/definition/", 
                                        idProperty: "JOB_NAME"
                                    }
                                );
            myStore.query("JOB00001"
                        ).then(function(results) {
                            var theJobDef = results[0];                             
                            dojo.byId("JOB_NAME").innerHTML = theJobDef.JOB_NAME;
                            dojo.byId("SCHEDULED_DAYS").innerHTML = theJobDef.SCHEDULED_DAYS;
                        });

        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true what Frans said about the cross domain restriction but dojo has this [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/iframe.html#dojo-request-iframe) to work around the problem.

```
require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframe){
  iframe("something.xml", {
    handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(xmldoc){
    // Do something with the XML document
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  });
  // Progress events are not supported using the iframe provider
});
```

you can simply use this and the returned data can be inserted into a store and then into the grid.

Comment: Nice one - just what I needed.  I'll start building around this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the Same Origin Policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Basically it restricts websites to do AJAX requests to other domains than the html page was loaded from. Common solutions to overcome this are CORS and JSON-P. However, remember that these restrictions are made for security reasons.

Comment: I guess I wasn't, but am now.  This is also what I needed - to understand what it was stopping it from working.  If I'm honest I didn't hold out too much hope that my approach would work - just didn't know why not ;-)   Thanks.